# Permission to create branches with gerrit

Tags: permissions, gerrit

So, I've read that you have "create reference" as a permission to create a branch. I've given it to a group of user on a certain projects but I keep getting a 403 forbidden.

Permissions are:

```
    Reference:  
    refs/for/refs/heads/*

    Create Reference 
    Developers

    Push 
    Developers

    Push Merge Commit 
    Developers



    Reference:  
    refs/heads/*

    Owner 
    Developers

    Read 
    Developers

    Create Reference 
    Developers

    Push 
    Developers

    Label Code-Review 
    CodeReviewers

    Submit 
    Developers
```

I had to add "Owners" to allow the group Developers to create branches on the UI. Just "create reference" on both refs/for/refs/heads/* and refs/heads/* didn't work.
Am I doing something wrong? This is the BaseProject inherited by all other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because only Owners are allowed to create a branch using the UI. Create Reference only applies to a regular push. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_owner).